# What is the root word of "unforgivable"?

Tags: morphology

I'm learning about morphology and got confused by the word "unforgivable" when identifying its root. Is it "forgive" or "give"? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The root is ***[forgive](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forgive?ref=etymonline_crossreference)*** (From Old English forgiefan : for + giefan)

[Unforgivable:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/unforgivable#etymonline_v_39619)

> 1549s from un (not) + forgivable.

Forgivable:

> forgive +able

(Etymonline)

Answer (score 1):

OED:

> **Forgive** (v.) Etymology: Old English forgiefan ( < for- prefix[1] + giefan : see give v.)

The sense of "for" is quite difficult to understand as it has a variety of effects upon its verb: in this case, it is probably

> b. With the sense of prohibition, **exclusion**, or warding off, as in forbid n.   Also with the sense of concealing from view: